# How to handle a question where the author has edited down to nothing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Was looking at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640024/how-can-i-validate-winsock-connection in the first poster review queue and purposely skipped it because I didn't know what the best thing to do was.

I know this needs to be flagged somehow, just not sure what the right way to flag is. Is it too broad? Unsalvageble? Off-topic? etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, it appears that the answer was to rollback; just wasn't incredibly obvious while going through review queue.. So if someone has a better answer please share, I'll delay accepting my own / delete it later.

Comment: Yes, the correct course of action is to rollback, just as for any other defacement.

Comment: Rollback **once**. If the post history shows earlier defacement -> rollback -> repeat, flag for mod attention.